# How do I log in to a site remotely using a script?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm trying to write a script to automate a repetitive task I currently do manually.  I would like to log in to a site remotely and inspect the returned page.

I've been doing this by sending a direct POST request (the site is PHP, I'm pretty sure it's Joomla) with my login details and data for the other fields of the form from the front page, but I'm getting either `sockaddrinfo` errors on the Net:HTTP Ruby library when I try a `HTTP.post()` (with data as a `param=val1&param2=val2` string), and a rejected redirect to home page if I use `HTTP.post_form` (using a Hash)

I'm willing to do this in any language, really, I just picked Ruby since it's a favorite for quick scripting.  If you have any ideas in bash, Python, etc. I'd be happy to try it.

I've tried variations on [some](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/788) [examples](http://travisonrails.com/2007/11/07/http-get-and-post-requests-with-ruby), to no avail.  Have any of you tried something like this with success?  Any stumbling blocks we beginners run into frequently?

Thanks for your time ^_^

-Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try mechanize:

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) (Python) which is written with your problem in mind:

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.com/")
# follow second link with element text matching regular expression
response1 = br.follow_link(text_regex=r"cheese\s*shop", nr=1)
```

Comment: There is a mechanize for Ruby as well.